# Dirac zero measure with almost everywhere statement

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $M$ be the Dirac zero measure, i.e. it is defined on all subsets of the real line as $1$ if the set contains $x=0$ and zero otherwise. Let $P(x)$ be a non-zero polynomial where only the powers of $x$ between $1000$ and $2000$ appear. Then $P(x)$ is equal to zero $M$-almost everywhere.

---

I can't see how this is true because

$P(x)$: non-zero polynomial (can't see why the power information is even relevant)

The property of $P(x)$ of points of $\mathbb R$ holds $M$-almost everywhere if the set $$\{x \in \mathbb R : P(x) \, \, \text{does not hold} \}$$ is null.

But this set is the same as a set with all zero polynomials and this under the Dirac structure would equal $1$ - not $0$. So it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is somewhat garbled. First of all, in the original statement, $P(x)$ is a polynomial function, not a property, so $\{x\in \mathbb R: P(x)\text{ does not hold}\}$ makes no sense. Second, it's not clear what you mean by "this set is the same as a set with all zero polynomials."

Here are some hints to help you think about the problem. Given that $P(x)$ has no powers of $x$ smaller than $1000$, what can you say about $P(0)$? Using this, what can you say about the set $\{x\in\mathbb R: P(x)\ne 0\}$? And what is the $M$-measure of this set?